# Unload load jQuery dataTables Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

Trying to integrate jquery dataTables in Rails 5.2.2. Page is loading with console error uncaught Reference Error (Turbolinks). When refresh again pages loads dataTables perfect.

Comment: You can remove turbolink from the your Gemfile, not sure if it's the best solution.

Comment: can you show your application.js file and your dataTables initialization js and html code?.. and also the exact error from the console